# Google Analtyics not registering transactions when using Measurment protocol

Tags: php, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I try to send http request to track eCommerce.

I got response **http_code=200** but, I can't see any event or transaction.

**Code:**

```
$fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'v' => 1,
        'tid' => "UA-xxxxxx-1",
        'cid' => $userid,
        't' => 'transaction',
        'ti' => $transaction_id,
        'tr' => $Transaction_revenue,
        'ts' => $Transaction_shipping,
        'tt' => $tax,
        'cu' =>'EUR'
    );
```

Hit:

> v=1&t=event&tid=UA-xxxxxx-1&cid=555&uid=123&ti=21&tr=20&tt=5&ts=2&pa=purchase&ec=Checkout&ea=Purchase

what could be the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I cloud not send transaction because my IP was blocked.

Comment: Which IP was blocked? and by who?

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think its not working.  I ran your hit against [debug collect](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits) to verify it.  Looks good to me.

> https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-3731463-1&cid=555&uid=123&ti=21&tr=20&tt=5&ts=2&pa=purchase&ec=Checkout&ea=Purchase

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026t=event\u0026tid=UA-3731463-1\u0026cid=555\u0026uid=123\u0026ti=21\u0026tr=20\u0026tt=5\u0026ts=2\u0026pa=purchase\u0026ec=Checkout\u0026ea=Purchase"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

Did you check the real time reports have you double checked your Tid?

> https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&tid=UA-3731463-1&cid=123&t=transaction&ti=124&tr=1&ts=1&tt=1&cu=EUR

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026tid=UA-3731463-1\u0026cid=123\u0026t=transaction\u0026ti=124\u0026tr=1\u0026ts=1\u0026tt=1\u0026cu=EUR"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

Could also be something with the values you are sending in the second one.

Comment: I have verified it too and all looks good, but i cant see the transaction in the reports (not in the real time reports and not in the E-commerce reports)

Comment: It takes 24 -48 hours for processing to finish and for you to see data in the standard reports.   How long did you wait?

Comment: double check tid then

Comment: try sending a normal pageview or an event hit those you can check in realtime reports.  At least then you will know that your account is working.

Comment: Add an answer with your solution I haven't heard of an IP issue before you may help someone in the future.   Accept your answer and you will get points :)